# Load Directional light by default

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to load Directional light by default when I am selecting the 3d object file. Totally I have five loaders for showing the object in the editor window. when I am selecting the object it will in without any color in this picture

**Image**

[image]

[selected 3d object in the three.js]

here I want to load directional light by default when the object is loaded in the window.

how can I add the directional light object for the selected 3d object?

anyone help me to find the solution.

Comment: The picture attached is missing.

Comment: Your screenshot looks like the [editor](https://threejs.org/editor/). Are you trying to asking how to do this in the editor, or are you using it as a base for something you're creating?

Comment: exactly the screen shot is showing the editor. now i want to add directional light object. the threejs providing to add light manually but i want to add light when the object is loaded in the editor

Comment: You'll need to modify the editor to do that. Unfortunately I am unfamiliar with its code and won't be able to help you further.